# Ler apenas uma parte de um arquivo .txt em Java

Tags: java

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um bot de Discord e queria que ele pegasse o ID da Guild e do Chat fiz ele escrever automaticamente quando alguém digitasse -setarbot Guild: 430119147146444807 Channel: 437245715576520716 em um arquivo chamado guilds.yml e eu queria fazer algo para ler esse arquivo somente pegar o ID da Guild e do Channel

e depois fazer retornar true com um boolean.

Comment: O site não proverá uma solução completa para você, tente colocar algum código e exemplificar a parte em que está com problema. O pessoal do site tentará te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Dependecias do arquivo pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Não esqueça de passar o Path do arquico corretamente

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    try {
        Map<String, String> map = mapper.readValue(new File("guilds.yaml"), Map.class);
        System.out.println(ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(mapToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE));
        System.out.println(map.get("id"))
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: aqui para min não funcinou o mapToStringStyle...

Comment: Eu utilizo dessa forma: ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();Map<String, String> map = mapper.readValue(new File("guilds.json"), Map.class); com o meu arquivo sendo Json.